# ncat sessions with random TOR Exit Router

Tags: tor, netcat, antivirus

I am playing around with netcat for a while. I was trying to create a reverse shell from my laptop to a virtualserver. The command I typed in was the following `ncat -lkvnp 4444`.
After some time, several connections were established from different ip addresses, including **185.220.101.147**, **185.220.101.243** (which are both Tor Exit Routers) and [**195.74.76.194**](http://ipaddress.is/195.74.76.194) which is hosted by avast.com

I don't know much about the TOR network or how antivirus systems work. Does someone know what is going on?

This was the output one minute ago:

```
Ncat: Version 7.70 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Listening on :::4444
Ncat: Listening on 0.0.0.0:4444
Ncat: Connection from 95.211.190.199.
Ncat: Connection from 95.211.190.199:29248.

Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.




Ncat: Connection from 185.189.167.14.
Ncat: Connection from 185.189.167.14:52399.
�
```

Both Ip addresses are unknown to me.

Comment: @Carcigenicate neither my virtual server nor my laptop has avast installed

Comment: Avast also offers a VPN service, so its possible an abuser was performing network scans from the Avast VPN. Similarly, people using Tor to scan networks as well.  Port 4444 is potentially used by I2P software as a proxy port which is why it may be a target for scanning. Metasploit may also use it for connecting back. So it seems like a port of interest for these reasons, mainly I2P.

Answer (score 0):

It could be just a zombie army of machines, controlled by malware, looking for another victims.

Machines running old TOR clients, can be hacked, as know vulnerabilities may be exploited by experts or just script kiddies with [Metaexploit](https://www.metasploit.com/).

Your IP is part of [ASN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_(Internet)#ASN_Table) (Autonomous system).
They target anything inside that IP range.
Continuously scanning everything live that responds to knows ports, like your 4444 or 22 (SSH), 3389 (RDP), 5900 (VNC) and so on.

That's why a good and easy measure of security, is change the port number to another random one, that only you knows what.
Trying to guess what that port is, by protocol inspection, is time consuming and discourage malicious activity.

**EDIT:** Getting attacked by a machine owned by Avast, seems that they are searching for it intentionally with their own software. Port 4444 is not part of TOR protocol (9050 or 9150), but a known windows security flaw exploited by Msblast Worm:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/threats/threat-search?query=Virus%253aDOS%252f4444

Comment: One of the IP address is hosted by avast.com...wouldn't be there a huge security problem if a machine owned by a security company is controlled by malware?

Comment: They are aiming for companies, to warn them about security issues.